# Expected Values in a Uniform Distribution

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

I have to calculate the following: 
$$
E[a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}]
$$
where $a=b=\frac{1}{2}\times10^{i}j$. We have that $i$ is uniformly
distributed on say the $[0,1]$ interval and $j$ is also uniformly
distributed on the $[0,1]$ interval. Both are independent. I have
so far simplified this to:
$$
E[2a^{1/2}]=2E[a^{^{1/2}}]
$$
$E[a^{1/2}]$ is $E[(\frac{1}{2}\times10^{i}j)^{1/2})$. We know that $E[g(x,y)]=\int\int g(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$.
Substituting this for what we have, we obtain that $E[a^{1/2}]=\int\int(\frac{1}{2}10^{i}j)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(i,j)didj$.
Given that $i$ and $j$ are independent, I obtain that the previous
expression simplifies to $\int\int\frac{1}{4}(10^{i}j)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(i)f(j)didj.$ Moreover,
We know that $f(i)=f(j)=\frac{1}{2}.$ This then simplifies to $\frac{1}{16}\int\int10^{i}j\, didj$

I am stuck after this point and do not know how to proceed. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I should also add that the two random variables are independent.

Comment: Sorry to both you again, but if we have a constant c, can we say that E[f(cx)]=f(c)E[f(x)]?

Comment: I actually had a typo. The original expression shouldnt be E[B^a*b] but rather E[(B^a*b)^1/2]. Do I have to take a double integral now? After your comment I realized my mistake.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Its not from either. Its a problem Im working on

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the need for the $a$ and the $b$; if $a=b$ wouldn't it have been simpler to just ask us about $E[a^{1/2}]$? (I don't think the question is so unclear that it ought to be closed, am just curious for the motivation behind separate $a$ and $b$ variables.)

Comment: You are right. I should have left it  in the way you have suggested.

Comment: Note that the double integral you have at the end\* can be split into a product of two single integrals. $\:$ \*(I have not checked your working up to that point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in my now erased comments
\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[B^ab]&=\mathbb{E}[B^a]/2\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 B^a \text{d}a\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 e^{\log(B)a} \text{d}a\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\log(B)}\int_0^1 e^{\log(B)a} \log(B)\text{d}a\\&=\frac{1}{2\log(B)}[e^{\log(B)}-1]\\&=\frac{B-1}{2\log(B)}\end{align*}
Now that the question has changed, 
$$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{B^ab}]=\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{B}^a]\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{b}]=\frac{\sqrt{B}-1}{\log(B)}\,\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: As I have re-edited the question above, Its actually E[(B^a*b)/2)^0.5]. I am trying to re-work it.